# find a pair of plankton Species which are correlated and a pair which are not correlated

Tags: r

[plankton image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwhY5.png)
ABOVE IS THE IMAGE I WANT TO USE IN R TO find a pair of plankton  Species which are correlated and a pair which are not correlated

Comment: Have you managed to read the data into R yet? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: How many plankton species do you have - is it just the 3 in your image in columns B:D? What do the values in those columns mean? You want them to be correlated (or not) in regard to what other variables?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort.